# Python3 Using Variables from Python in os.popen() statement (WINDOWS)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.7

I'm standing in front of following problem.
I am building a small uninstall Java Tool with python3.

I can read out everything I need but when im trying to send the Uninstall command to Windows I cannot get the parsing done right.

The command to search for the installed software looks like this:

```
wmic_output = os.popen('''wmic product where "name like 'Java 8 Update %%'" get name''').read()
```

Without any Variables in the os.popen string everything works fine. Trying now to execute the command seems more tricky...

```
    productname = str(uninstallcall[inx])
    # Check if Version is installed, if so uninstall
    wmic_output1 = os.popen('''wmic product where "name like '%s'" get name''').read()
    result1 = parse_wmic_output(wmic_output1 % (productname))
```

And yes the productname variable prints fine when doing so :/

For parsing Im using following snipped found here http://autosqa.com/2016/03/18/how-to-parse-wmic-output-with-python/:

```
def parse_wmic_output(text):
    result = []
    # remove empty lines
    lines = [s for s in text.splitlines() if s.strip()]
    # No Instance(s) Available
    if len(lines) == 0:
        return result
    header_line = lines[0]
    # Find headers and their positions
    headers = re.findall('\S+\s+|\S$', header_line)
    pos = [0]
    for header in headers:
        pos.append(pos[-1] + len(header))
    for i in range(len(headers)):
        headers[i] = headers[i].strip()
    # Parse each entries
    for r in range(1, len(lines)):
        row = {}
        for i in range(len(pos)-1):
            row[headers[i]] = lines[r][pos[i]:pos[i+1]].strip()
        result.append(row)
    return result
```

Comment: `%s`, are you trying to insert a variable into that position? if so you need to do `"some %s variable" % variable_to_inser`. Or a cleaner way, do `f"some {productname} here"` (`f` being important at the start of the string).

Comment: Yes indeed. I've tried to ad a Variable into the position where `%s` was located. The Option you've providet already answers my problem :) Tank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `%s`, are you trying to insert a variable into that position? if so
>   you need to do `"some %s variable" % variable_to_inser`. Or a cleaner
>   way, do `f"some {productname} here"` (f being important at the start
>   of the string). – @Torxed

This resolves into my problem as following:

```
wmic_output = os.popen(f'''wmic product where "name like {variablename}" get name''').read()
```